# Why don't large multiplications cause buffer overflows in php

Tags: php, buffer-overflow

In a piece of code, I see a function that essentially takes a number in params, representing a time, and multiplies it to get it's value in seconds.

In my mind, a buffer overflow was possible in this case; If I entered a number large enough, when multiplied it would cause a buffer overflow. However, after bugging around, trying to enter larger and larger numbers, I wasn't able to produce it.

My question is, what is PHP doing in this case to prevent the buffer overflow?

I thought it might have to do with the memory allocation limit in php, but I also went ahead and increased that to close to infinity, but there was still no buffer overflow.

Comment: Why would multiplying a number cause a buffer overflow? Do you know what a "buffer" is?

Comment: You might be confusing buffer overflow with integer overflow.

Comment: "Memory allocation to infinity!" Sorry, saw that and thought of some programming starship captain.

Comment: A buffer overflow is a bug. It should not happen. It's not happening here, so it's a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example in the documentation referring to [*integer overflow*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow):

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it
>   will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which
>   results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return
>   a float instead.

If you `var_dump` out your return value, you'll probably notice that it has been cast to a float instead of an integer (assuming you're actually arriving at a result that causes integer overflow).

The maximum size of an integer is also platform dependent- the maximum size for an integer on a 32-bit machine is 2147483647, but on a 64-bit machine it is 9223372036854775807

**Update**

From the docs on floating point types:

> The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of
>   ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common
>   value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

That is 1.8 x 10 ^ 308, or 18 followed by 307 zeros (more than the [number of atoms in the observable universe](http://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/) by a lot)

Comment: Thanks for the answer watcher. It's a bit of a naive question, but what if I entered a ridiculously large number, that even a float couldn't handle?

Comment: It would have to be a really really really big number, but I would suspect that your operation would return a NaN result that you can check for with `is_nan()`

Comment: It'll give a result that [is infinite](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-infinite.php).... e.g. `$result = 1.0e308 * 1.0e308);`